# Why is a PowerShell module installed by Install-Module not listed by Get-InstalledModule?

Tags: windows, powershell

In PowerShell (Core 7.4.1) I have installed the PowerShell module *Microsoft.WinGet.Client* by running `Install-Module Microsoft.WinGet.Client` (run by PowerShellGet 2.2.5). When I run `Get-Module -ListAvailable`, it is listed. I can also run its commands like `Get-WinGetVersion`, and afterwards it is also listed by `Get-Module`. However, when I run `Get-InstalledModule`, it is not listed. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This is the subject of the post
[What is the difference between Get-InstalledModule and Get-Module -ListAvailable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105056/what-is-the-difference-between-get-installedmodule-and-get-module-listavailable)

Answer by Prasoon Karunan V :

> `Get-InstalledModule` is part of `PowerShellGet` and will list installed modules using `Install-Module` cmdlet, But `Get-Module -ListAvailable` shows modules from all locations mentioned in `$env:PsModulePath` location.

References :

- [Get-InstalledModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/get-installedmodule?view=powershellget-3.x)
- [Get-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: This explains why `Get-Module` can in general list modules that `Get-InstalledModule` does not list. But it does not explain why `Get-InstalledModule` does not list a module that was installed via `Install-Module`.

Comment: There is no answer, except that this is the way it works - Get-InstalledModule does not consult `$env:PsModulePath` and only uses mechanisms established via [PowerShellGet](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellGet/2.2.5). The two commands were created with different populations of packages in mind and do what they were programmed to do, by Microsoft's design.